# freeswitch - all users list - not "registred only"

Tags: voip, freeswitch

I use a webservice with

```
/opt/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli -x 'show registrations'
```

and I have the list with registred users (with phone connected).

I need the list of all users (disconnected phone too).
Exists a fs_cli command or another way to achieve this without connecting to the web interface ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the command:

`list_users`

in fs_cli